# Fortranでinterfaceを書く際の型の定義

Tags: fortran

次のCの関数をFortranから呼び出すFFIを書く必要があります

```c
typedef struct {
  int x, y;
} int2;

int2 f(int2 a) {
  int2 b;
  b.x = 2 * a.x;
  b.y = 2 * a.y;
  return b;
}
```

この関数を呼び出すためのFFIを次のように書いてみました(test.f03)

```
module mymod
  type :: int2
    integer :: x, y
  end type
  interface
    function f(a) result(b)
      type(int2) :: a, b
    end function
  end interface
end module
```

しかし以下のようなコンパイルエラーとなります

```
test.f03:8:16:

       type(int2) :: a, b
                1
Error: Derived type ‘int2’ at (1) is being used before it is defined
```

エラーメッセージは定義前に`int2`型を使用していると読めますが、どのようにすれば（どこで定義すれば）interface内でint2を使うことが出来ますか？

使用したコンパイラ：

```
$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 8.2.1 20181127
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: 参考:[How to use a user-defined-type in a Fortran interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13858145)

Answer (score 0):

リンクを頂いたので自己回答しておきます
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13858145

```
module mymod
  type :: int2
    integer :: x, y
  end type
  interface
    function f(a) result(b)
      import :: int2         ! import explicitly
      type(int2) :: a, b
    end function
  end interface
end module
```

のように明示的に`import`を行うことで解決できます。
これはFortran2003で追加された機能で、例えば以下に解説があります
http://www.nag-j.co.jp/fortran/fortran2003/Fortran2003_8_6.html